# Get all friends for multiple given users using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to compile a list of all of the friends who my friends are following on twitter (friends of friends) using tweepy.  So the multiple given users will be the users I am following

I use a cursor to return all of the users I am following
Then attempt to print all of that users friends

```
for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends).items():
    print friend.screen_name
    user = api.get_user(str(friend.screen_name))
    for f2 in user.friends():
        print f2.screen_name
```

However I run into several issues the first being that only 20 friends are printed for each user(`user.friend`).  The second issue is I keep receiving the rate limit error. How can I modify this code to handle rate limiting and return all of each given users friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/ids), you'll see that you can request up to 5,000 friends at a time.

There is no way to escape the rate limit of 15 lookups every 15 minutes.

Comment: So does that imply you can only lookup one friend per minute? and in that case couldn't I just import the time module and sleep for 60 seconds on upon getting each user?

Comment: Yes, that's what most scripts do. Sleep for 61 seconds (just in case your clock is running fast!)

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in your code and you'll no longer receive the limit error message.

```
#to wait rather than printing the time limit error       
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```